# How to align the lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Experts,

I have 1000's of lines captured from the xml file in below format in notepad++.

```
sample text
  <Parameter Name="FilePath" Value="/Test_01/path_01/vendor/dev/outbound"/>
<Parameter Name="FileName" Value="*.txt"/>
        <SubParameter Name="HostIP" Value="192.165.10.5"/>
        <SubParameter Name="UserId" Value="win-001"/>
```

But I want to resize all the 1000's of lines in below format. Manually moving each line to the beginning of the line is tedious. Please assist me

```
<Parameter Name="FilePath" Value="/Test_01/path_01/vendor/dev/outbound"/>
<Parameter Name="FileName" Value="*.txt"/>
<SubParameter Name="HostIP" Value="192.165.10.5"/>
<SubParameter Name="UserId" Value="win-001"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ use menu => **Edit** => **Blank Operations** => **Trim Leading Space**.

Answer (score 1):

Do a find/replace.  enter this in the Find What box:

```
^\s+
```

And nothing in the Replace with box.

Find one or more whitespace characters at the beginning of the line and replace with null, effectively deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> several times (or hold) to reduce indent (both space and tab symbols).